# Timestamp to date in php and mongodb

Tags: php, mongodb

I spent 3 days trying to solve this with no success.
I'm using the MongoDB PHP Library and i'm trying to convert a timestamp in a valid date using the example in the PHP Docs but it's always returning 1970-01-17.

The code is:

```
  $utcdatetime = new MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime(1453939200);

  $datetime = $utcdatetime->toDateTime();

  var_dump($datetime);
```

Answer (score 14):

The **[documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongodb-bson-utcdatetime.php)** states that the constructor takes in an integer parameter representing the timestamp in milliseconds, you are providing a timestamp in seconds hence the invalid date result.

Multiply the value by 1000 to get the timestamp in milliseconds thus return a valid datetime object converted:

```
$timestamp = 1453939200 * 1000;
$utcdatetime = new MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime($timestamp);

$datetime = $utcdatetime->toDateTime();

var_dump($datetime);
```

Comment: Hi chridam, thanks for the answer but now i'm getting 1969-12-08 05:14:47 as date. Any idea why?

Comment: It sounds like you're running a 32-bit version of PHP that can't handle numbers as large as a timestamp in milliseconds. There is no workaround for this aside from either running 64-bit PHP, or not using this Mongo object at all since you apparently want a DateTime. `$foo = new DateTime(); $foo->setTimestamp(1453939200); var_dump($foo);`

Comment: Would agree with @Sammitch here on this one

Comment: Thanks again guys. @Sammitch, phpinfo is telling me i'm using a 64-bit version of PHP. I can show the result of 1453939200 * 1000 as float.
I want to use the mongo object because i will insert this data in a database. Using DateTime, the date is saved as a array of date, timezone_type and timezone instead of just a date object in mongo. Probably the problem is in the driver and/or library of php-mongo.

Answer (score 0):

To anyone looking for this:
You have first to convert the value in a timestamp and after that you will be able to convert it in a valid ISODate.
Eg:

```
  $utcdatetime = new MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime(strtotime($date));
  $date2 = new MongoDB\BSON\Timestamp(1, date($utcdatetime));
```

Comment: UTCDateTime takes a millisecond-based timestamp as parameter, strtotime returns a second-based timestamp. http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongodb-bson-utcdatetime.php